# How do i setup GLFW in VS Code? GLFW Error

Tags: visual-studio-code, glfw

I am developing a project and in process i need to setup GLFW in VSCode. I am using MinGw as compiler and generated the glfw build files using cmake configuring for MinGw. I got the files and placed them in main `c:/mingw` . I placed `glfw3.dll` inside bin, `libglfw3dll.a` inside lib and `GLFW/glfw3.h` and `GLFW/glfw3native.h` inside include. `"PS: i have placed these files in mingw as well as in my project".` And then i add these lines inside tasks.json "-lglfw3" but at the execution terminal shows cannot find -lglfw and if i remove this then glfw and glad functions in main.cpp shows as error.

> task.json

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"command": "g++",
"type": "shell",
"reveal": "always",  
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Build",
        "group": "build",
        "windows": {
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "--std=c++17",
                "-I", "${workspaceFolder}",
                "-I", "${workspaceFolder}/thirdparty/include",
                /*===LIBS===*/
                "-lopengl32",
                "-lglfw3",                  
                /*===END OF LIBS===*/
                "main/main.cpp",
                "-o", 
                "builds/windows/Stupefy",
            ]
        },

        "linux": {
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "--std=c++17",
                "main/main.cpp",
                "-o", 
                "builds/x11/Stupefy"
            ]
        },

        "osx": {
            "suppressTaskName": true,
            "args": [
                "-g",
                "--std=c++17",
                "main/main.cpp",
                "-o", 
                "builds/osx/Stupefy"
            ]
         }
      }
   ],    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that `GLFW/glfw3.h` is in your "thirdparty/include" folder. If it's not, add the path to that file as `-I` argument (or move it there)

Make sure that path to `%your_glfw_folder%/lib-mingw-w64/glfw3.dll` is specified by `-L` argument. (Or move it into more convenient location. As far as path to that file is specified by `-L` argument, you're good to go).

Make sure that libraries `glfw3`, `opengl32`, `gdi32` are linked with `-l` parameters (you're missing `-lgdi32`)

For GLAD, make sure that path to its `includes` folder is listed as `-I` argument or its contents are in your "thirdparty/include" folder

Also add path to `src/glad.c` to your arguments list.